# How to count values in a column based on condition in another column in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, percentage, countif

How can I count number of positive results in column Profit/Loss if only setup is ob?
I want to store the result in another cell where I can monitor percentage of my trade based on the setups
So for example in this Table I would get 2 of 3 trade is successful if setup is ob.

---

### Data sample

| Date | Profit/Loss | Bias | Setup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31/10/2022 | $1,000.00 | Up | fvg |
| 01/11/2022 | -$200.00 | Down | ob |
| 02/11/2022 | $2,000.00 | Up | br |
| 03/11/2022 | -$150.00 | Up | mt |
| 04/11/2022 | $1,500.00 | Up | fvg |
| 05/11/2022 | $1,500.00 | Down | ob |
| 06/11/2022 | $2,000.00 | Up | mt |
| 07/11/2022 | -$200.00 | Down | br |
| 08/11/2022 | $3,000.00 | Down | fvg |
| 09/11/2022 | -$1,000.00 | Down | fvg |
| 10/11/2022 | $2,000.00 | Down | ob |
| 11/11/2022 | $3,000.00 | Up | fvg |

Comment: Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** (NOT as IMAGE/Spreadsheet LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. Your question may be closed, if it isn't [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a minimal example.[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use** [`Countifs()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550) function.
To get the percentage of the number of Profit/Loss values > 0 and setup = "ob" Divided by the count of instances of setup = "ob".

```
=COUNTIFS(B3:B,">0",D3:D,"=ob")/COUNTIFS(D3:D,"=ob")
```

[image]

### Using Lambda

```
=LAMBDA(PnL, Setup, TO_PERCENT(COUNTIFS(PnL,">0",Setup,"=ob")/COUNTIFS(Setup,"=ob")))
       (B3:B,D3:D)
```

[image]

Used formulas help
[**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`COUNTIFS`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550) - [**`TO_PERCENT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094284?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you very much for the path, I just need to hack it a little bit to get te percentage